# python function for time, speed and direction using GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, raspberry-pi

I have a question regarding speed, direction, and timer functions. I want to make five different speeds for ultrasonic generator with a time of up to 10 seconds and directions (left and right). I want them with a graphical user interface (GUI) to be possible to press the speed, time, and direction bottoms using a raspberry pi touch screen.

I would like some tips for python code that will help me do this especially the time function.

Comment: Your question is too vague for StackOverflow which is specifically for programming questions only - you seem to be asking for recommendations for libraries, tools, and techniques. Maybe try on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: No, I do not need libraries. I want a python function for time, but can be applied using GUI library..